# Problems importing large file in Core Data with background thread

Tags: swift, multithreading, csv, core-data, grand-central-dispatch

I am running into some trouble importing a large .csv file in OS X using Core Data on a background thread.

My simplified data model is a Dataset which has a to-many relationship to many Entries. Each entry is a line in the .csv file (which has a bunch of attributes that I'll leave out for brevity). Following what I have read about efficiently importing lots of data, along with how to make a progress indicator work properly, I have created a managed object context for the purposes of going the import.

I am having trouble with two things:

1. I need to hang on to a reference to the new Dataset at the end of the import, because I need to select it in the popup. this will be done in the main thread, but for efficiency (and to make my NSProgressIndicator work) the new dataset is created on the background thread, with the background MOC.
2. From what I read, batching the import, so that the background MOC saves and resets, is the best way to stop the import from eating up too much memory. That does not turn out to be the case so far - it looks like gigs of memory is being used even for files in the tens of megabytes. Also, once I reset my import MOC, it cannot find the data for the inDataset, and so cannot create the relationship between all subsequent Entries and the Dataset.

I've posted the simplified code below. I have tried refreshObject:mergeChanges, without good results. Can anyone point me at what I am doing wrong?

```
let inFile  = op.URL
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0)) {


            //create moc
            let inMOC = NSManagedObjectContext()
            inMOC.undoManager = nil
            inMOC.persistentStoreCoordinator = self.moc.persistentStoreCoordinator




            var inDataset :  inDataset = Dataset(entity: NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Dataset", inManagedObjectContext: inMOC)!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: inMOC)

            //set up NSProgressIndicator here, removed for clarity

            let datasetID = inDataset.objectID
            mocDataset = self.moc.objectWithID(datasetID) as! Dataset



            let fileContents : String = (try! NSString(contentsOfFile: inFile!.path!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)) as String
            let fileLines : [String] = fileContents.componentsSeparatedByString("\n")



            var batchCount : Int = 0

            for thisLine : String in fileLines {
                let newEntry : Entry = Entry(entity: NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Entry", inManagedObjectContext: inMOC)!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: inMOC)
                //Read in attributes of this entry from this line, removed here for brevity
                newEntry.setValue("Entry", forKey: "type")
                newEntry.setValue(inDataset, forKey: "dataset")
                inDataset.addEntryObject(newEntry)


                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {          
                    self.progInd.incrementBy(1)
                }


                batchCount++
                if(batchCount > 1000){
                    do {
                        try inMOC.save()
                    } catch let error as NSError {
                        print(error)
                    } catch {
                        fatalError()
                    }
                    batchCount = 0
                    inMOC.reset()

                   inDataset = inMOC.objectWithID(datasetID) as! Dataset
                 //   fails here, does not seem to be able to find the data associated with inDataset

                }

            }// end of loop for reading lines


                //save whatever remains after last batch save
                do {
                    try inMOC.save()
                } catch let error as NSError {
                    print(error)
                } catch {
                    fatalError()
                }


               inMOC.reset()


                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    //This is done on main queue after background queue has read all line
                    // I thought the statement just below would refresh mocDataset, but no luck
                   self.moc.refreshObject(mocDataset, mergeChanges: true)


                    //new dataset selected from popup


                    let datafetch = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Dataset")
                    let datasets : [Dataset] = try! self.moc.executeFetchRequest(datafetch) as! [Dataset]
                    self.datasetController.addObjects(datasets)
                    let mocDataset = self.moc.objectWithID(datasetID) as! Dataset
                    //fails here too, mocDataset object has data as a fault
                    let nDarray : [Dataset] = [mocDataset]
                    self.datasetController.setSelectedObjects(nDarray)

                }


        }
```

Comment: When executing on a global dispatch queue, it's not safe to call `self.moc.objectWithID`. I strongly suspect, `self.moc` is associated to the main thread, or to any other _known_ thread and thus cannot create managed objects in another thread.

Comment: It's also not safe, to create a managed object on a private dispatch queue, and then import the reference in another closure executing on a different thread. You can however use and import the _objectID_ in different threads, that is, "transfer" it between threads. If you want to access an object in a different thread, recreate it in this thread for example with `objectWithID(:)` using the moc associated to this thread or queue.

Comment: Hi CouchDeveloper, and thanks for your comments. I am fairly sure that the use of self.moc is restricted to within the main_queue (at the end). It might be that calling the main queue from the global dispatch queue is screwing things up, though.

Comment: In answer to your second comment - well, that's what I thought I was doing :)  Up at the top,e where it say":             let datasetID = inDataset.objectID
            mocDataset = self.moc.objectWithID(datasetID) as! Dataset  I am using objectWithID to pass the reference to the dataset object, but then when i get back into the main queue by the end, if i print out the object, i get:  mocDataset <Plexus.Dataset: 0x6080002a9a20> (entity: Dataset; id: 0x100000b <x-coredata://94FCD091-DA03-44DF-ADFF-17A797620718/Dataset/p4> ; data: <fault>)

Comment: Well, of course you need to obtain the `datasetID` with the appropriate MOC - here `inMOC`. The objectID is unique for each managed object and thus is the same in every MOC. There may be other issues, too, though. For example, use the more "modern" approach to create a MOC - with specifying the concurrency type: `init(concurrencyType ct: NSManagedObjectContextConcurrencyType) `

Comment: An additional hint: there are two different "objectIDs": the "temporary" ID which is for objects not yet saved into the persistent store, and the "permanent" ID - which is available when the object has been saved, or when it has been explicitly obtained with method `obtainPermenantIDForObjects`. It's not possible to use a _temporary_ object ID in different mocs. So, try to obtain the permanent one before passing it to other threads.

Comment: Thanks! Making your suggested modifications allows me to hang on to inDataset all the way though and select it in the popup afterward. I'm still having trouble with the amount of memory used, but at least things are functional, now.